# Convention in writing endomorphism as tensor

Tags: tensors

If I have an endomorphism $f:V\to V$ of a finite dimensional vector space, I can identify it canonically with an element of $V\otimes V^*$ but also with an element of $V^* \otimes V$.

In the mathematical community, is there a preferred one among the two choices?

Comment: Not really. ${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ is generated by $\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ and the dual $V^*$ by
$\{\beta^1,...,\beta^n\}$ then mapping linearly $V\to V$ using them is
posible via
$$v\longmapsto \beta^k(v)b_j=\sum_sv^s\beta^k(b_s)b_j=v^kb_j.$$
But since It is known that $\beta^k\otimes b_j$ are used to generate
$V^*\otimes V$ then also for a generic element $\phi\otimes w$ there
can be employed to transform
$$v\longmapsto\phi(v)w.$$
If you dub this as $T_{\phi\otimes w}$ then the assignment
$$T:V^*\otimes V\to \hom(V,V),$$
given by $\phi\otimes w\mapsto T_{\phi\otimes w}$ is going to be an
isomorphism.

Comment: perhaps this could help you to decide which is preferred

Comment: the map $\phi\otimes w\longmapsto w\otimes\phi$ is also an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Note that I do not ask how to find an endomorphism: I know how to find it and it is somehow "well-known". If you like I can describe it. The question is which space do people prefer to identify End(V) with.

Comment: We've $\hom(V,V)={\rm End}(V)$ and usually there is a matrix associated to each endomorphism, in that way I suppose that this would be a preferred characterization because calculations are streamlined

Comment: By End(V) I meant hom(V,V)

Comment: Let us forget about bases and matrices. You are stating that it is better to identify $v\in E\mapsto \phi(v) w$ with $\phi\otimes w$ than with $w\otimes \phi$ because then calculations are streamlined. What do you mean by streamlined?

Comment: **As an example**: how do you express the basis change of a symmetric, positive defined, non degenerated  bilinear $V\times V\to\mathbb R$ if we change basis on $V$?

Comment: How must **be** the basis change on $$  for the bilinear has a diagonalization?